# WSO2 Bad_certificate in starting of API manager

Tags: wso2

Good afternoon,
I use api manager 4.0 in my company and I realized that the `wso2carbon` certificate at `JKS` is about to expire on the 25th of January. I tried to generate a new certificate following the documentation but I get the following error:

> ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket.
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR - BinaryDataReceiver Error while reading from the socket. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

The above error can occur when all root, intermediate, and signed certificates are not correctly imported to the key store.
Therefore, please try to recreate and import it correctly, and you can refer to the below details to renew the certificates.

- You can create a new key store by following this document[1] and configuring it as the primary key store in the toml file.
- To renew the CA-singed certificate, you can follow this document[2].
- Once you got the new certificate or key store, please make sure to add the public key of the primary key store to the client trust store.
- If you are generating a new key store, you can point your old primary Keystore as the Internal key store in the toml file[3], and a new key store should be pointed as the primary key store in the toml file.

Once you have done the change, **please restart the servers to apply them correctly.**

[1]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/#creating-new-keystores
[2]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/renewing-a-ca-signed-certificate-in-a-keystore/
[3]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/configuring-keystores-in-wso2-api-manager/#configuring-the-internal-keystore

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
  the error mentioned above occurs after generating the new certificate following the steps in doc [1] "Creating a keystore using a new certificate".

I tried to generate a signed certificate as doc[2] shows, but the following error occurred:

`code`
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Comment: if you have followed the steps correctly when you are getting this exception? (eg: Starting the APIM pack, API calls, connecting to other nodes.. etc) What is your deployment pattern(distributed or one node only)? Do you have an LB fronted with APIM?

Comment: I'm getting this error on starting of the api manager. My deployment is distributed, and runs in kubernetes. It only has the kubernetes LB on the front.